# When I have two cards with cohort would there tap ability works at the same time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent has two [Ondu war cleric](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOndu%20war%20cleric%5d). He taps them both and said he gains 4 life. But I believe he couldn't use the second one with only two of those cards, because cohort said you need another untapped ally

Comment: Are those the only two ally cards he has?

Comment: He had more but only used those two for four life points, i believe he needed atleast 3 ally's or 4

Comment: I am not sure on how the timing would work for tapping, I would agree that you would need to tap more but hopefully someone with more knowledge can come in and clear it up

Comment: Yeah i wasnt sure either

Answer (score 4):

He can only gain 2 life

When you activate an ability, the first thing you do, is pay it's cost.

> 602.1a The activation cost is everything before the colon (:). An ability’s activation cost must be paid by the player who is activating it. 
>   
> 602.2. To activate an ability is to put it onto the stack and pay its costs...

In this case that means that you need to tap the Ondu war cleric and an other untapped ally. They will be tapped before the ability is put on the stack so you won't be able to then activate the second war cleric as he is already tapped.